# Free up more Inactive or File Cache memory in Activity Monitor

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, memory, memory-management

I have found a application has Clean Memory function.

[image]

I think it uses the original PURGE function, but after checking (using Activity Monitor), I see that it's likely to be more free File Cache than Purge command (or it can operate independently of the PURGE command). Please refer my experiment in below.

1. Below is first information in Activity Monitor

[image]

2. Then, I use Clean Memory function (FREE UP 600+ MB File Cache)

[image]

3. Finally, I use PURGE command (FREE UP more 400+ MB File Cache)

[image]

My question: 
Refer [free mem as function of command 'purge'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415252/free-mem-as-function-of-command-purge/11419163#11419163)
1. What it has used technology to make Clean Memory function (I have research https://opensource.apple.com/ for a week but did not find relevant information)?
2. (optional) The difference between Clean Memory function and PURGE command?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150650/is-it-ok-to-use-classic-malloc-free-in-objective-c-iphone-apps

try malloc(), free() from NSData or NSMutableData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my solution.

It's simple create data then release it.

Answer (score 2):

What the Memory Clean application seems to do is just to allocate memory and release it. If you have Xcode you can run Instruments and track the allocations of Memory Clean. As soon as you hit the "Clean Memory" button you will see in Instruments that the allocated "Total Bytes" are nearly the same as the one displayed as "free memory available" in Memory Clean. You can see the same in the Activity Monitor as well.

About the `purge` command, it seems to use different mechanism. Tracing it with `dtruss` (`dtruss purge`) shows the following result on the last line:

```
vfs_purge(0x7FFF5320CDE8, 0x7FFF5320CDF8, 0x7FFF5320CE48)        = 0 0
```

According to the source of [vfs_syscalls](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/bsd/vfs/vfs_syscalls.c), and more specifically the comments:

> /*
>    * Purge buffer cache for simulating cold starts
>    */

Needless to say, purging file cache is a bad idea and it has only one good application - benchmarking disks.

Comment: Tks for comment, can you expalin more detail about "allocate memory and release it"? How to do it?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but probably the fastest one is `malloc()`. You can check the [following question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150650/is-it-ok-to-use-classic-malloc-free-in-objective-c-iphone-apps).